# Simulate time series given temporal auto-correlation functions

Tags: autocorrelation, time-series, random-process

Given a random process $x[n] \in \mathbb{R}$ (say of length $N$) and all correlation functions such as:

\begin{align}
\langle x[i]\rangle\\
\langle x[i]x[j]\rangle\\
\langle x[i]x[j]x[k]\rangle\\
\vdots
\end{align}

1. Is it possible to simulate a single realization of the random process and if so how?
   Thinking abstractly about the problem it seems like any trajectory could be mapped onto a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and there is some probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Sampling this distribution and then picking out the corresponding trajectory would then constitute of "simulation" of a single realization that I am looking for. It seems like given information about all of the auto-correlation functions it should be possible to determine the probability distribution. This seems related to the [inverse moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem).
2. What if we truncate and only have up to $k$-time correlation function with $k<N$? My guess is that it is not possible to uniquely generate the probability distribution but it should be possible to (non-uniquely) simulate a process with matching auto-correlation functions up to $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible method that you could possibly use.

Let's model your random process $x[n]$ as an auto-regressive (AR) process of order $P$, that is,
$$x[n] + \sum_{p=1}^P a_px[n-p] = c + \epsilon[n]$$
where $c$ is some constant that I will set to 0 in what follows for the sake of simplicity, $\{a_p\}_{p=1}^P$ are the parameters of the AR model and $\epsilon[n]$ is some *white noise* of variance $\sigma^2_\epsilon$.

Multiplying each side of the above equation by $x[n-l]$ for some $l \ge 0$ leads us to
$$\left(x[n] + \sum_{p=1}^P a_px[n-p]\right)x[n-l] = \epsilon[n]x[n-l].$$
Now, taking the expectation on each side, we obtain the Yule-Walker equations
$$C_x[l] + \sum_{p=1}^P a_pC_x[l-p] = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if} & l > 0, \\
\sigma^2_\epsilon & \text{if} & l = 0
\end{cases}$$
using the fact that $\epsilon[n]$ and $x[n-l]$ are uncorrelated for $l > 0$ (you can see that from the equation of the AR process above). Using this equation with $l = 0, 1, 2, \dots, P$, you have $P+1$ equations to solve for the $P + 1$ unknowns (i.e., $\{a_p\}_{p=1}^P$ and $\sigma^2_\epsilon$).

You then have a model to generate a time series given the temporal auto-correlation.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It looks like this answers my question in the case that the stochastic process can be modeled as an AR process. I guess this does not work for more complicated processes, for example a process which follows a non-linear stochastic differential (difference) equation. Is this correct? I wonder if there is an approach that would work for a fully general random process.

Comment: I'm not aware of the existence of a "general approach" but I'm not an expert in that field.

Comment: Still, I believe my answer answers your question. You might want to ask a new question for the more general case you describe in the above comment.

Comment: I've asked the question on mathematics stack exchange asking for the more general approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104827/sample-instances-of-random-process-given-all-temporal-correlation-functions . There has been no attention there yet.